# Sci-fi/fantasy short short story: creepy bookstore matron

Tags: story-identification

I just watched Rick & Morty episode "Something Ricked This Way Comes" and laughed and laughed.. was reminded of a short short sci-fi/fantasy story I read in late 70s/ early 80s about a man that comes across a mysterious bookstore where customers are frozen in various poses in front of the shelves each staring into a book. The man suspects he's onto something supernatural, but treats the creepy matron of the store with sneering disrespect... grilling her with sarcastic questions, wondering aloud what makes a cliched character like her tick, literally asking her if she still has her period...The crone angrily shows him a book that he assumes will show his future, but it instead shows him a moment from his childhood and he realizes nothing in his future will be better than that memory and he becomes trapped in frozen contemplation like the others.

Comment: Do you remember anything about where you read it? In an anthology? A magazine?

Comment: @Mara
I read it in a short story anthology of some kind, I think. Spoiler - more detail about the childhood memory:
>! catching a fly ball at a baseball game

Comment: gdeff-That might be a different story.  I've read the one you're talking about and I'm pretty sure that the guy leaves the store at the end.  Something by Harlan Ellison, maybe?

Comment: The bookstore from that particular Rick & Morty episode is most certainly referencing the Steven King book though, *Needful Things*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went and checked my stash.  I believe the story is called: "The Cheese Stands Alone" and is by Harlan Ellison from his 1982 collection "Stalking the Nightmare".

"It was a bookstore.  Without a sign.  And within many men and women: browsing."  "They were not turning the pages."
"I'm certain I have it in hardcover". The little old turtle woman said.  How could there be fog in here."

"Where do you think you're going?.....You've got to stay, everybody stays."
[image]

Actually, I am now sure that it's the story because I just read the part with the disrespectful grilling.  He even asks about the consistency of her bowel movements!  That's Ellison for you.

Comment: And the story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v55n06_1982-03#page/n21/mode/2up).

Comment: Yes! Thanks, Emsley!